How to prove upper bound of this difference of the Sine Integral?
This exercise can be found in Mathematics LibreTexts (bottom of the page) . I have been stuck for about a day and have made minimal progress.
Let $S(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}$.
Show that for $k \ge 1$ $$|S(2\pi k) - S(2\pi (k+1)| \le \frac{1}{k(2k+1)\pi}$$
They give the additional hint that the identity $\sin (t+\pi) = -\sin t$ should be useful.
The best I have done is bound the difference by $\ln(1 + \frac 1k)$, which I note does approach zero as k tends to infinity, showing that the difference does become arbitrarily small, but this is not what the question asks. This also does not use the hint.
\begin{align}
\lvert S(2\pi k) - S(2\pi (k+1)\rvert & = \lvert\int_{2\pi k}^{2\pi(k+1)}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt\rvert \\\\
& \le \int_{2\pi k}^{2\pi (k+1)}\lvert \frac{\sin t}{t}\rvert dt \\\\
& \le \int_{2\pi k}^{2\pi (k+1)}\frac {dt}{t} \\\\
& = \ln (1 + \frac 1k)
\end{align}
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

One ambiguity here is whether or not $k$ is intended as integer. However, based on plotting it looks like the inequality is valid even for non-integer $k$.

I tried, got an estimate tighter than yours, but not as tight as desired, and did not use the hint. The derivation; underlying MathJax

Try
$$\int_{2 \pi  k}^{2 \pi  (k+1)} \frac{\sin (t) }{t} \, dt=\int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \frac{\sin (2 \pi  k+t+\pi ) }{\pi  (2 k+1)+t} \, dt$$
for integer $k$.
$$ \left|-\int _{-\pi }^{\pi } \frac{\sin (t)}{\pi  (2 k+1)+t}\cdot dt\right| =\frac{1}{\pi  (2 k+1)}\cdot  \left|\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\frac{\sin (t)}{1+ \frac{t}{\pi  (2 k+1)}} dt\right|= \frac{1}{\pi  (2 k+1)}\cdot \int_0^{\pi } \sin (t) \left| \frac{1}{\frac{t}{\pi  (2 k+1)}+1}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{\pi  (2 k+1)}}\right|  \, dt$$
